# Update table row entry by value in matching row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, match, row, repeat

I have

```
mydf1 <- data.frame(unique.id = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "cc", "bb"), date = c("1/2/21", "1/4/21", "1/8/21", "1/5/21", "12/5/20"), A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I need to update the value of A such that for any instance of multiple rows with a given unique.ID (for example rows 1 & 3), the value A is updated to a new value (2) for the row with the later date. This would result in the output of the following

```
mydf2 <- data.frame(unique.id = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "cc", "bb"), date = c("1/2/21", "1/4/21", "1/8/21", "1/5/21", "12/5/20"), A = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1))
```

Where row 3 has A = 2 because both rows 1 and 3 have "aa" and row 3 has the later date, and rows 2 & 5 share a common unique.id but row 2 has the later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it easily if you sort the dates and count the rows grouped by the id

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf1 <- data.frame(unique.id = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "cc", "bb"), date = c("1/2/21", "1/4/21", "1/8/21", "1/5/21", "12/5/20"), A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

mydf2 <- data.frame(unique.id = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "cc", "bb"), date = c("1/2/21", "1/4/21", "1/8/21", "1/5/21", "12/5/20"), A = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1))

mydf1 %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(date)) %>% 
  group_by(unique.id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(result = dplyr::row_number())
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   unique.id [3]
#>   unique.id date           A result
#>   <chr>     <date>     <dbl>  <int>
#> 1 bb        2020-05-12     1      1
#> 2 aa        2021-02-01     1      1
#> 3 bb        2021-04-01     1      2
#> 4 cc        2021-05-01     1      1
#> 5 aa        2021-08-01     1      2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>